# c# json newtonsoft conversion

Tags: c#, json

Im trying to create a serialize string from this json:

```
report_details = {
'reportTypeLang' : 'conversations',
'reportDirections' : {
'selected' : 'inbound'
},
'times' : {
'dateRange' : 'Last5Minutes'
},
'filters' : {
'sdfDips_0' : 'in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410'
},
'dataGranularity' : {
'selected' : 'auto'
}
```

so far i have created these classes:

```
public class ReportDetails
{
    public string reportTypeLang { get; set; }
    public ReportDirections reportDirections { get; set; }
    public Times times { get; set; }
    public Filters filters { get; set; }
    public DataGranularity dataGranularity { get; set; }
}
public class ReportDirections
{
    public string selected { get; set; }
}
public class Times
{
    public string dateRange { get; set; }
}
public class Filters
{
    public string sdfDips_0 { get; set; }
}

public class DataGranularity
{
    public string selected { get; set; }
}
```

and tried to use this code to build the data:

```
ReportDetails ReportDetails = new ReportDetails();
ReportDetails.reportTypeLang = "conversations";

ReportDirections reportDirections = new ReportDirections();
reportDirections.selected = "inbound";

Times Times = new Times();
Times.dateRange = "Last5Minutes";

Filters Filters = new Filters();
Filters.sdfDips_0 = "in_AC10033A_AC10033A-410";

DataGranularity DataGranularity = new DataGranularity();
DataGranularity.selected = "auto";

string report_details = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ReportDetails);
```

but this only seems to result in this object:

```
"{\"reportTypeLang\":\"conversations\",\"reportDirections\":null,\"times\":null,\"filters\":null,\"dataGranularity\":null}"
```

How do i popluate all the sections as per the original json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not assign the other properties. Therfore their serialized values remain null.

Just add them, like you assigned a reportTypeLang:

```
ReportDirections reportDirections = new ReportDirections();
reportDirections.selected = "inbound";

ReportDetails ReportDetails = new ReportDetails();
ReportDetails.reportTypeLang = "conversations";
ReportDetails.reportDirections = reportDirections; // and so with the other props
```

---

And as a side-note: there's a cool feature *paste JSON as classes* which autogenerates the neccessary classes for you, if you don't wanna write them down yourself:

[image]